# CSS Background Image Doesn't Appear in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, background-image

I have the following CSS which sets the background image, but it doesn't work in Safari. It doesn't even set the background color, even though that should be a fallback. I can't install Safari on Windows so I can't even test it!

```
.oops-body {
    background: url('/img/oops-bg.jpg') center/cover no-repeat #1b1d37;
    min-height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

And the HTML

```
<body>
<div class="oops-body">
</div>
</body>
```

```css
.oops-body {
 background: url('http://placehold.it/500') center/cover no-repeat #1b1d37;
 min-height: 100vh;
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="oops-body">
 </div>
```

This was the screen shot from a co-worker who has Safari:

[image]

By the way, it *does* work in mobile Safari. I tested on my iPhone.

Comment: Works as expected for me. Safari Version 12.0 (14606.1.36.1.9)

Comment: this is for sure a cache issue

Comment: @TemaniAfif Cannot be a cache issue because all the images are new, both the foreground images and the background image. If it was a cache issue, then they would not display the new foreground images. They are all new file names.

Comment: It may have been a spurious network connection. Co-worker states that it did work later even before we deployed changes in accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this,

```
background-image: url("http://placehold.it/500");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center top;
```

instead of just using `background`.

Answer (score 1):

replace your `background` css with this

```
{
   background-image: url("image.png");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-attachment: fixed;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Why `fixed`? I'm sure it will look fine as `fixed` but I didn't have that in mind at first.